# How can I reset a Wii that has no access to settings?

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii

I got a Wii from a church, it has no access to settings, online, or the eshop. Attempting to access any of these results in a "system files corrupted" error. I must clarify, I have absolutely no access to the system settings, I can only look at the storage.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: You may be able to use some unofficial methods to re-flash the Wii with custom firmware, but this is extremely gray area and I'm not sure if the details can be posted on SE.